# How do I use a column in one table twice, to show the associated values of two foreign key columns in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table like this:

Id (int), command (text), ...

Another like this:

Command id fk (int), sub command id fk (int), ...

The two columns shown in the second table simply are foreign keys to the id column in the first.

I'd like to make a query that presents the two columns of the second table, but replaced with values from the command column in the first table (text values). How do I do this in MySQL?

Sorry if this question is confusing or presented wrong.

Comment: It would be great if you can add some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Some example data and nomenclature would be useful. But, since you are missing these for your example tables, let's assign some.

Say it's the `command` table that has the fields `id, command` with the data

```
id | command
------------
1  | CREATE
2  | USE
3  | DESTROY
```

and the `assoc` table that has the fields `cmd_id, sub_id` (nice and concise) with data

```
cmd_id | sub_id
---------------
   1   |   2
   2   |   3
```

Then, you would get a listing of the text content of each command and subcommand by, for instance

```
SELECT cmd1.command AS cmd, cmd2.command AS sub
FROM assoc a, command cmd1, command cmd2
WHERE a.cmd_id = cmd1.id
    AND a.sub_id = cmd2.id
```

This would result in

```
cmd       | sub
-------------------
CREATE    | USE
USE       | DESTROY
```

This result is constructed by combining all the rows of all the specified `FROM` tables, and then picking the requested `SELECT` data from these combined rows that match all the `WHERE` criteria. These combined rows look something like

```
(a)          | (a)          | (cmd1)     | (cmd1)          | (cmd2)     | (cmd2)
assoc.cmd_id | assoc.sub_id | command.id | command.command | command.id | command.command
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 2            | 1          | CREATE          | 1          | CREATE
1            | 2            | 1          | CREATE          | 2          | USE
1            | 2            | 1          | CREATE          | 3          | DESTROY
...
```

etc, containing all possible combinations. For clarification, the labels in parentheses are the table aliases I used in my query. As you can see, the middle row is an example of a match to my query, so 'CREATE' and 'USE' from that row are used in the final result set.